# I have sorting by Month function but somewhat I work only one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm using javascript and angular to sort data.
I tried to filter my data by month.
It works first time and then somehow It doesn't work after then. 
and data table disappear on the browser.
How can I make this filter button constantly as like it suppose to be.

Here's some parts of my files that related.

```
----- In my `controller`


   function CreateTableController($scope,$http, listsFactory){
   listsFactory.getLists().then(function(response){
      $scope.lists = response.data;
      console.log($scope.lists);
    }, function(error){
     console.error(error);
    });

   $scope.filter = function(year, month) {
     console.log('filtering');
     $scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.lists;
     $scope.lists = $scope.lists.filter((record) => {
       console.log(record);
       return record.date.includes(`${year}-${month}`);
     });
   };


----------- this is a part of my `html` files

      <section class="filteringBymonth">
          <input name="year" type="text" ng-model="date.year" >
          <input name="month" type="text" ng-model="date.month" >
          <button name="filter" ng-click="filter(date.year,  
           date.month)">Filter</button>
      </section>




  -------- this is my `component`(it works like `.directive` but somewhat  
             better way) and `factory` file just in case

   sampleApp.component('createDataTable',{
     template: require('./create-data-table.html'),
     controller: 'CreateTableController',
     controllerAs:'createTableCtrl'
   });

   sampleApp.factory('listsFactory', function($q,$http){
     return {
     getLists: function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
        httpPromise = $http.get('something.json');                                                
       httpPromise.then(function(response){
          deferred.resolve(response);
       }, function(error){
         console.error(error);
       });
        return deferred.promise;
       }
     };
   });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates the problem. We have no way to reproduce it from what is shown. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your filter function where you override *$scope.lists* with filtered list but never restore it to the original list:

```
$scope.filter = function(year, month) {
 console.log('filtering');
 $scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.lists;
 // original list is overridden here
 $scope.lists = $scope.lists.filter((record) => {
   console.log(record);
   return record.date.includes(`${year}-${month}`);
 });
```

I changed it to

```
$scope.filter = function(year, month) {
   console.log('filtering');
   // store original list
   $scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.unfilteredLists || $scope.lists;
   $scope.lists = $scope.unfilteredLists.filter((record) => {
     return record.date.includes(`${year}-${month}`);
   });
  };
 };
```

where line

```
$scope.unfilteredLists = $scope.unfilteredLists || $scope.lists;
```

ensures that we have original list stored in *$scope.unfilteredLists*

also, you use unnecessary $q in your factory, just return $http.get, which is a promise by its self.

I created working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/o6QVWfEi0WUBpPlsk3kV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for great answer! and thank you for the factory part tip too!